# Can someone explain why is my question opinion based?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I posted a [question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/28115/popping-shoulders) a couple of days ago, and it was closed as "opinion based", I have my answer, and I'm satisfied with it. But I would like some enlightenment as to why it has been considered as opinion based, that way I can avoid similar mistakes in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever it's worth, I don't think your question was heavily opinion based. I'll quickly add that most everything has some degree of opinion (ie: what's the optimal back exercise for overall development), and some are entirely opinion (what's the best running distance for a 30 year old?)

But the only *actual question* you asked was this:

> Are these type of events normal? I've been working out for a while,
>   but I've never heard/felt my shoulder pop before.

You didn't actually ask what to do about it, what the cause was, or what treatment to pursue. You simply asked if it's normal. As such, I didn't vote to close your answer because I thought that it fell more on the side of people being able to offer up personal, but not really heavily opinionated experience.

It's akin to asking how many people have a Costco in 30 miles. There's no research studies being referenced, but I think it's a fair enough question that doesn't really involve as much opinion as it does fact.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with the others. I don't think it was an opinion-based question. I do think that it falls under that Too Broad category where it's difficult to come up with a single "most right" answer, but that's a separate Close reason.

Answer (score 0):

Basically because any answer that someone might give is just a guess. You could have injured something, used too much weight, been at an odd angle, been a little stiff, etc etc.

"Why did X happen" type questions are often going to be mostly opinions, especially in something like fitness where the motion is transitory and can't easily be explained without video or visual evidence.

You will also (if it stays open long enough) get many answers such as the one you received. Yes, you may also have loose tendons. You might also have stretched ligaments. Or any number of other things, and following what worked for one person may or may not help you, and may injure you.

Comment: I didn't ask a "why" tho...